# Query from DB with regexp

Tags: php, sql

In database table one i have realpath - details.html?cat_id=48&id=295,
in table two - have id 295. Can i select cell's from table one where id in url = id table two? I do this, but it not working:

```
$sql = one.realpath, two.id FROM one, two WHERE one.realpath REGEXP '[0-9]+$' = two.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit - 
As you mentioned Number shouldn't be static -

You can try this -

```
$myNumber = 295; // If you want to define it in a variable and then use if
```

Or try this -

```
$myNumber = myCheckingFunction(); // If the value is returned from a function
```

Or try this -

```
$myNumber = $someRowFromDB['field_name']; // If you are trying to fetch it from a db row
```

Then you can substitute it to the code like this -

```
$searchNeedle = 'id=' . $myNumber;
$query = "select * from tablename where two.realpath like '%$searchNeedle'";
```

Comment: ok, but number don't static. i must check number and than select from table

Answer (score 0):

If your table one looks like this:

```
select * from one;

+-------------------------------+
| realpath                      |
+-------------------------------+
| details.html?cat_id=48&id=295 |
| details.html?cat_id=48&id=234 |
+-------------------------------+
```

And if you exec in sql console your expresion:

```
SELECT one.realpath REGEXP '[0-9]+$' TEST FROM one
```

This query returns

```
+------+
| TEST |
+------+
|    1 |
|    1 |
+------+
```

For this reason, when you try to do

```
WHERE one.realpath REGEXP '[0-9]+$' = two.id
```

You are doing:

```
WHERE '1' = two.id
```

You could try this query. It could be better but it´s working:

```
SELECT one.realpath, two.id FROM one
INNER JOIN two ON (one.realpath REGEXP CONCAT('id=',two.id, '$'))
```

This is the result:

```
+-------------------------------+-----+
| realpath                      | id  |
+-------------------------------+-----+
| details.html?cat_id=48&id=295 | 295 |
+-------------------------------+-----+
```

It´s important add 'id=' because if you don´t add this, you could have results like this:

```
SELECT one.realpath, two.id FROM one
INNER JOIN two ON (one.realpath REGEXP CONCAT(two.id, '$'))

+-------------------------------+----+
| realpath                      | id |
+-------------------------------+----+
| details.html?cat_id=48&id=295 |  5 |
+-------------------------------+----+
```